# fadeout audio volume on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

can anyone tell me how can i do this, the callback for volume is like this

`<a href='#' onClick="api_setVolume(players[0],0); return false;">Set volume (0%, mute)</a>`

`<a href='#' onClick="api_setVolume(players[0],0.5); return false;">Set volume (50%)</a>`

`<a href='#' onClick="api_setVolume(players[0],1); return false;">Set volume (100%)</a>`

and i need to make a single button in jquery, when click a link fadeout sound gradually. 
Thank you.

Comment: slider? what do you think?

Comment: HTML 5 range input perhaps. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: And where is help there???

Comment: You want everything easy don't you? Ranges are better suited input for volume than three links.

Comment: Look man, i allredy have the range, but i want this, and i need to know if its possible, because i like to make when click FORWARD button to change the song, i like to make current song stop gradually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function fadeOut(callback) {
    var volume = 1;
    var fade = setInterval(function () {
        api_setVolume(players[0], volume);
        volume -= .1;

        if (volume === 0) {
            clearInterval(fade);
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function myCallback() {
    // do Something
}
</script>

<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick="fadeOut(myCallback);">Fade Out</a>
```

This is untested but should work. It will reduce the volume by 0.1 every 1 second. You can change the values as you wish.

Comment: This worked for me, Thank you but if you help me just one more little thing, i need to make it return after all, because when pres next the sound gradually faded but next song dont hear nothing :S.

Comment: Updated the answer with the callback which is fired when the volume reaches 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that takes the player whose volume you want to reduce and a fade speed in %/s (that's percent/second) as parameters. In the function I'm assuming `api_getVolume(player)` is a function in the API you're using.

```
<script>
function fadeOut(player, fadeSpeed) {
    var curVolume = api_getVolume(player),
        reductionAmount = curVolume * (fadeSpeed / 1000);
    var fadeInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var newVolume = curVolume - reductionAmount;
        if (newVolume < 0) {
            return clearInterval(fadeInterval);
        }
        api_setVolume(player, newVolume);
        curVolume = newVolume;
    }, 100);
}
</script>

<!--Example button usage with fade speed of 50%/s (so the fade lasts 2 seconds)-->
<button onclick="fadeOut(player[0], 50);">Next</button>
```

Here's an explanation for my math for calculating the `reductionAmount`:

Since the interval is firing every 100 ms, we need to convert the fade speed from %/s to decimal/100ms.
So:

`%/s / 10 = %/100ms`

then

`%/100ms / 100 = decimal/100ms`

This decimal is then multiplied by the current volume to obtain the amount of volume to be reduced for each 100 ms interval.